# Google sheets function that outputs URL of spreadsheets in a specific folder?

Tags: google-sheets

Google sheets function that outputs URL of spreadsheets in a specific folder? I would like to use "importrange" for a dynamic set of files, where a new file is created every month and added to the importrange.

Comment: you can get the id's of each sheet stored in the sheet and then generate url for importrange function if this solves your problem i can help you with the codes.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can do this with a custom formula and a Web App.*

#### More Information:

There is no Sheets formula which allows you to obtain file IDs simply by giving a folder. You can however use a custom function to extend the function of formulae and get the data this way.

As per the documentation on [custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#advanced):

> Unlike most other types of Apps Scripts, custom functions never ask users to authorize access to personal data.

Which means it is not possible to directly call `DriveApp` as this requires authentication. The list of supported services can be found on the custom function page, but for this, we can use `UrlFetchApp`.

#### Code:

First you will need to write a `doGet()` function, and publish your script as a web app:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFolderById(e.parameter.folderId).getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");
  var IDs = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    IDs.push(files.next().getId())
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput().setContent(IDs.join()).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}
```

Follow the `Publish > Deploy as Web App` menu item, and set the settings to `Execute the app as: me` and `Who has access to the App: anyone, even anonymous`, and press save. Make sure to copy the script URL that appears in the following modal.

With this Script URL, you can then create your custom function:

```js
function getSheetIds(folderId) {
  var url = "script-url"
  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url + "?folderId=" + folderId).getContentText();
  var vals = [];
  return resp.split(",")  
}
```

Making sure to paste the web app URL as the value of the `url` variable. Save the script, and return back to your Sheet.

You can then call the function from Sheet using the following formula:

```
=GETSHEETIDS(folderId)
```

Where `folderID` is the ID of the folder from which you want to get the list of Sheet IDs.

#### Example:

[image]

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)